# Stata: clttest command gives me different results every time

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, stata

I am running something like

```
clttest truth, cluster(userid) by(envyfree)
```

and every time I run the command I get different results, which is super shady. Truth and envyfree are 0-1 variables. Any possible explanations would be most helpful.
​​​​​​​
I attach two figures showing the different results:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used stata, but in R there is there is a function called `set.seed`. What this does is seeds a random number generator, meaning any result from random data can be replicated http://rfunction.com/archives/62.

Would be surprised if there wasn't an equivalent in stata. If your test requires a random sample then that should make it replicable.

Comment: Thanks @willbutdontwanna. These results are not generated with random data, but with a meaningful dataset that keeps constant. But I still generate different results!

Comment: I meant the actual test itself involves a degree of randomisation. Which if I am interpreting correctly seems to be the case: http://fmwww.bc.edu/RePEc/bocode/c/clttest.hlp

let me know if retaining the randomisation doesn't work though and I'll delete the post if not.